# setting cache for preferences list in android

Tags: android, caching, preferences

I'm trying to change the background of a preference screen in my app. I was able to add an image by doing this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.applicationsettings);

        findViewById(android.R.id.list).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_bg));
    }
```

The background comes up, but when I scroll, it shows a black cache
in a normal list, I set the cache hint,,,, but here I cannot do that!
is there a way around it?

I have tried: "findViewById(android.R.id.list).setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);"
but it didn't work.

**Update**
The solution is:

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_bg));
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Thanks to: user370305

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to use that before... but this method doesn't even exists!...... I've also tried setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) and setWillNotCacheDrawing(true) and still didn't work

Comment: Try this, ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
 listView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false); and let me know what happen..

Comment: Oh it actually worked! Its a shame I didn't think of that... Thank ALOT!

Comment: If you don't mind I can post it as a Answer, so you can accept is as right answer. This will help you and other So user also..

Comment: Oh. By the way, no offense meant when I said "regardless of the complexity involved" in my comment above. A fellow on SO, when asked to accept an answer, replied that the solution wasn't to complex. Hence the addition. ;-)

Comment: Ummmm, the thing is,,, I donno how to accept a comment :S. O he just posted it as an answer :),,,, Will do, thanks for notifying me ^_^

Comment: @user1347945: Now you know. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_bg));
listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and let me know what happen..